# Convert from Microsoft Word to Media Wiki Markup Style

Tags: ms-word, mediawiki

How do I export a word document to media wiki markup style

I have been trying to do it by following the steps given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:WordToWiki
but all in vain, not getting it.

Any help please.

Comment: This page is made specifically for biowikifarm.net, but has some helpful general tips as well: https://biowikifarm.net/meta/Converting_Word_to_Mediawiki_text

Answer (score 11):

Best way is to use [Open Office](http://openoffice.org/)

1. Open the Word document in [Open Office](http://openoffice.org/) Writer.
2. Go to File / Export.
3. Under File format choose MediaWiki (.txt).
4. Click Save (or Export).
5. Open the new file in a text editor and copy the contents to the clipboard.
6. Paste the text to a Wikipedia article.

That is copy and pasted from the document you linked to.

For Open Office 4.15 you have to add the  extension [Sun Wiki Publisher 1.1](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/sun-wiki-publisher) with the extension manager.

If you don't want to install OpenOffice, another option is the [Word2MediaWikiPlus](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Word2MediaWikiPlus) extension.

Comment: I added the following extension [Sun Wiki Publisher 1.1](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/sun-wiki-publisher)  to Open Office 4.15  and it worked. It first hang up when I added it with the ExtensionManager , I killed OpenOffice Writer, removed it and added it again and then it worked.

Comment: For info the Word2MediaWikiPlus extension page now shows "This extension has been archived. This extension has not been maintained for some time, and no longer supports recent releases of MediaWiki."

Answer (score 6):

In Microsoft Word 2016 I use the plugin "Microsoft Office Word Add-in For MediaWiki" (already suggested by Jake). https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12298

To make it work in Microsoft Word 2016 (version 16.0). I followed these instructions but replaced "15.0" in the instruction to "16.0",

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/using-microsoft-office-word-add-in-for-mediawiki/449726c2-6d08-45e1-919a-4b5082ab4b5b

Comment: If you are running the 64 bit edition of Windows, do the same thing for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\Text Converters\OOXML Converters\Export\MediaWiki`

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has released an add-in for Microsoft Word that lets you export a doc file to MediaWiki formatting (as a .txt file). It's fairly decent.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12298

Comment: I have downloaded it. But I dont know how to use this. Help required to figure out.

Comment: btw, source code i at: http://wordmediawikiaddin.codeplex.com/
MS funded its development: http://wikieducator.org/Microsoft_Launches_Open_Source_Filter_for_Mediawiki

Comment: Note it doesn't work on OS X according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:WordToWiki#Possible_issues_with_alternative_solution

Comment: LibreOffice works better, but both LibreOffice and MS fails to export/upload
images.

Comment: I know I'm late to the game, but here are the usage instructions (from another answer's instructions link): Start Word and open or create a document.  Select File-.Save As and when you get to the "Save As" dialog, you'll see "MediaWiki (*.txt)" in the list of supported formats in the "Save as type" list.

Comment: Does not seem to work with newer versions of MS Office

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be doing this a lot, consider installing the [FCK Editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_%28Official%29).  This has a Paste From Word button.

Comment: Please see also this wiki Q&A forum in start up phase: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wiki-edit

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way may be to install LibreOffice (http://libreoffice.org) and open the Word document in its Writer application, then from there do Export and save to Media Wiki txt file. The Copy-paste that text into the Media Wiki at edit mode

Comment: If you don't see the export feature, it means it wasn't bundled, but it's easy to fix: look for the `libreoffice-wiki-publisher` package/plugin and install it.

Answer (score 2):

but there was no way for adding images automatically  that won't work for libreoffice or the word plugin.

If you have only a few docs for converting to the mediawiki, it is ok.

But if there ar more the it is great deal of time and effort.

**For autom. Imageupload the only working solution was the discontinued project [Word2MediaWikiPlus](https://sourceforge.net/projects/word2mediawikip/).**

*If somethings has changed in the last years let it me now.*

But if not there are some solutions with work without image upload
 (if I found them i will add these entry here):
- on webserer projekt which generated very good wiki markup output there , i can' t remember the name.
- a commandline tool that do the conversion as input and output file